# Timezone confusion with switching CEST to CET

Tags: datetime, timezone, utc

I'm currently building a system where you can create normal appointments and recurring appointments like in Microsoft Outlook. The database stores the datetime values as UTC without the timezone. When creating recurring appointments, I store the start time in a separate column. Now my problem:

When a user creates a recurring appointment starting on `2021-10-01T20:00:00+02:00` (it will be stored as `2021-10-01T18:00:00Z` in the database) and ending on `2021-11-30T21:30:00+02:00` (it will be stored as `2021-11-30T19:30:00Z` in the database) recurring every wednesday and friday a week. So the duration of the appointments is 1 hour and 30 minutes.

If I now query all appointments in the timespan between `2021-10-01` and `2021-11-30` and the timezone of my local device is `CEST (Central European Summer Time (UTC+0200)) or CEDT (Central European Daylight Time (UTC+0200))`, all appointments are starting at `20:00` and ending at `21:30`. If I query all above appointments one month later (after `CEST` is switchted to `CET (Central European Time (UTC+0100))`, all appointments are starting at `19:00` and ending at `20:30` because of the timezone of my local device but I want the appointments to always start at the time it was initially created (In this example always from `20:00` to `21:30`.

What is the best approach for this? Should I store the timezone in which the appointment is created and convert it to this timezone at query time?

Comment: What technology are you using (database, datetime structure etc.)?

Comment: *In principal*, if you store the [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) with UTC date/time, and then query that object (at any point in time), you can always calculate the tz-specific UTC offset based on the rules for the given tz.

Comment: @MrFuppes I'm using a postgres database with columns as the TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE datatype. But I don't think it's relevant for my question as I'm asking for a concept on how to handle the switch between CEST and CET. I want the appointments to always have the same times regardless of CEST or CET.

Comment: What kind of confuses me is the *Central European Summer Time* vs. *Central European Daylight Time* part. That's what Windows uses afaik. But you can map it to a time zone from the [IANA database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), which I presume should be the reference. Such a mapping can be found [here](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/main/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml) btw. So, you'd use e.g. 'Europe/Berlin' as time zone. Once you have that, you can calculate the UTC offset for any date (not actually *any* of course... ;-))